# Drag and drop attachment from Gmail

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, gmail, email-attachments

In Chrome, Gmail allows attachments to be dragged from the email to the Desktop. For example, I can open up an email with an Excel spreadsheet attachment, click and drag the icon to my desktop, and it will appear on my desktop as an Excel spreadsheet that I can then open up and edit.

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/drag-and-drop-attachments-to-save-them.html

What I'd like to do is code a web application to allow me to drag a Gmail attachment to a drop area on my page and get the file.

After doing some additional research I found that, according to [The CSS Ninja](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout), dragging to the desktop works by setting the `dataTransfer` object in the drag event to contain a type of `DownloadURL`:

```
files[0].addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
     evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", fileDetails[0]);
}, false);
```

Where `fileDetails[0]` is the URL of the object to download from.

However, when I drop on my page and check my event object, I find that the `dataTransfer` doesn't contain anything at all. No `DownloadURL` type, no text string or anything like that. It's completely empty.

By contrast, when I drag a PNG image or a hyperlink from the page, the `event.dataTransfer` object contains plenty of data.

What am I missing here?